# make \cite{my_references to show only title at particular place in latex document

Tags: bibtex

I am working with bibtex in latex. And I write references using bibtex.Its done. But want to print specific entries (year or title etc) of .bib file particularly at specific places in my document. How I can do it.
Work that have done.

**sample.bib**

```
@book{is4562000,
  title={Indian Standard Plain and reinforced concrete--code of
practice (IS 456 : 2000)},
  author={Cement and Concrete Sectional Committee, CED 2},
  journal={New Delhi: },
  year={2000}
  publisher={Bureau of Indian Standards}
}

@book{aci1981aci,
  title={ACI Standard Building Code Requirements for Reinforced
Concrete (ACI 318-77)},
  author={ACI Committee 318},
  series={ACI standard 318-77},
  url={https://books.google.co.in/books?id=amEOfgtA-DYC},
  year={1981},
  publisher={American Concrete Institute}

@STANDARD {aci31877,
    title        = "ACI Standard Building Code Requirements for
Reinforced Concrete (ACI 318-77)",
    organization = "American Concrete Institute",
    institution  = "American Concrete Institute",
    author       = "ACI Committee 318",
    language     = "English",
    number       = "ACI standard 318-77",
    year         = "1981"
}
```

**citedemo.tex**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
\title{Individual Spread Footing}
\author{Manpreet Kaur}
\maketitle

This is demo \cite{is4562000}
 \cite{aci1981aci}
 ~\cite{aci31877}

 \bibliography{sample}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

[image: bibdemo.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use package `biblatex` and run `biber file` instead of `bibtex`. And put
authors which are not real names into `{{...}}`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{demo.bib}
@book{is4562000,
title={Indian Standard Plain and reinforced concrete--code of
        practice (IS 456 : 2000)},
author={{Cement and Concrete Sectional Committee, CED 2}},
journal={New Delhi: },
year={2000},
publisher={Bureau of Indian Standards},
}

@book{aci1981aci,
title={ACI Standard Building Code Requirements for Reinforced
        Concrete (ACI 318-77)},
author={{ACI Committee 318}},
series={ACI standard 318-77},
url={https://books.google.co.in/books?id=amEOfgtA-DYC},
year=1981,
publisher={American Concrete Institute},
}   
@STANDARD {aci31877,
title        = {ACI Standard Building Code Requirements for
    Reinforced Concrete (ACI 318-77)},
organization = {American Concrete Institute},
institution  = {American Concrete Institute},
author       = {{ACI Committee 318}},
language     = {English},
number       = {ACI standard 318-77},
year         = 1981
}   
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{demo.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citepublisher}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
    \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printlist{publisher}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}

This is demo \cite{is4562000,aci1981aci,aci31877}
and the publisher of \texttt{aci1981aci} is \citepublisher{aci1981aci}
and of \texttt{is4562000} \citepublisher{is4562000}.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, sir for correcting my mistakes . I am tried to print  number of (aci31877) reference and tried to print full author name, institution. But my  did not shows number instead of this it shows reference id in place of number. And did not show full author name.

Comment: see my edited answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: No, sir . Your first reply solve my problem and want that. In your previous reply author name is printed , But not full author name.  And as per your suggestion when I write \citeinstitution{aci31877} instead of showing name of instituion , it shows reference ID. I want to print some entries (full-authorname, number, series etc) of .bib file at specific places of document. What I can do?

Comment: Hello, I found a new problem , I want to produce publisher entry from bib file. I tried to write \citepublisher{is4562000} and \citeOPTpublisher{is4562000} . But it did not worked. How I can print publisher entry from .bib file?.

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: Thank you, Herbert. Got my mistake. Now it print publisher name.

Comment: I am facing a problem in subtitle. I want to \cite subtitle from complete titlename , But do not want to redefine subtitle/shorttitle in @book{is4562000}. I used title={{ttle.subtitle}}, But it did' t worked. Is there any way to \citesubtitle picked from fulltitlename?

Comment: You should use the field `subtitle=...` in your bibfile entries. Then you can simply use `\citesubtitle`

Comment: I used this as you suggest, But t did not worked for me. Can we print subtitle (IS 456:2000) from this  title={Indian Standard Plain and reinforced concrete--code of
        practice (IS 456 : 2000)},  automatically ? . I mean to say that I do  not want to define extra subtitle. But want to print ( IS 456:2000 ) from above title={   }.

Comment: no, because you do not have a field `subtitle={code of practice (IS 456 : 2000)},`

Comment: Ok. But as per  your suggestion when  define subtitle ={ IS 456:2000} in @book and use \citesubtitle {s4562000}. It did not worked for me.

Comment: you have to define `\citesubtitle`. just like `\citepublisher` which was also unknown.

Comment: Sir, I added same code \DeclareCiteCommand {\citesubtitle}, {\printlist{subtitle}}  just like,  you added for publisher. And when I used \citesubtitle. It did not show anything . Why?

Comment: provide it as a new question with your code. I have no crystal ball so I cannot say what you did wrong without your code.